# How to record the data every day to another google sheet at a certain time?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using google sheets to track my investments. Now I want to record the total investment value from  L11 in "Portfolio" sheet every day at 4 PM to "Dashboard" sheet. Now I tried to use the code available online but it is showing an error in the last line.

```
function scorekeeper(){
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Portfolio");
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Dashboard");
  var score = sheet1.getRange("L11").getValue(); 
  var row   = sheet2.getRange("A1").getValue(); 
sheet2.getRange(row,2).setValue(score );
}
```

> Error
> Exception: Cannot convert '' to int.
> scorekeeper.

So how to do this properly and then add trigger to this. I have to use that data to plot a graph for visual presentation.

Comment: what values do `score` and `row` contain?

Comment: "score" is getting the exact data from the sheet but "row" is showing empty

Comment: what. are. the. values?

Comment: Score is a the total investment value which is a number. row is currently empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am quite sure that cell A1 is empty, and it is supposed to contain the row number of the destination sheet, where you want the value to be stored.

Maybe adding

```
SpreadsheetApp.flush()
```

before

```
var score = sheet1.getRange("L11").getValue();
```

would help, if you A1 contains a formula that calculates the row number. Otherwise, check its content or set the `row` variable value to a number.

Comment: added what you said above but still the same error at the same place. There is some thing wrong at row. Also changed the row value same error.

Comment: Where do you get the mentioned error, is it the line with sheet2.getRange(row,2).setValue(score );? If this is the case, row is definitely not a number. Try with var row=1;

Comment: Yes the error is in that line only and I just changed the A1 value in sheet "Dashboard" to 1 now the code is working fine and I can see the data from "Portfolio" sheet here in the "Dashboard" sheet. Now I want to create a new row every time the code runs and paste the data in that new row, so that I can use the trigger to do it every  day.

Comment: sheet2.getRange("A1").setValue(row+1);

Comment: Perfect. Worked fine. Now I can plot the graph. Also how to add the date adjacent to that. Because it will be triggered every day.

Comment: sheet2.getRange(row,3).setValue(new Date());